# ¿por qué me sale el siguiente error al iniciar un proyecto en react usando visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al iniciar un proyecto en react usando visual studio code, me sale ese error

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Ten presente que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está en que configuración duplicada o en conflicto entre los archivos 'package.json' y 'baseconfig'.

Busqué algo de info y para solucionarlo podes probar estas opciones...

Verifica si tienes la misma configuración en ambos archivos (package.json y baseconfig). Si es así, elimina la configuración duplicada o en conflicto de uno de los archivos.

Si no podes intentar desinstalar y volver a instalar las dependencias de ESLint y React. Primero, desinstala las dependencias ejecutando npm uninstall eslint eslint-plugin-react y luego vuelve a instalarlas con npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react.